# how to be pythonic in a 2d nested for loop comprehension for pulp

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension, pulp

I can't get over this hump in my program.  I would like to reduce this repetitive code to a simpler code. To make short these are constraints for pulp.

I have 2 shift patterns:  "Shift_Pattern_1" and "Shift_Pattern_Master"

Employees is a list with names inside.

```
 Days:["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",    
 "Saturday", "Sunday"]

Shift_pattern_Master = ["Morning", "Mid", "Night"]
Shift_pattern_1 = ["Morning", "Night"]

Week1={"Monday":2, "Tuesday":2, "Wednesday":3, "Thursday":2, "Friday":2,    
"Saturday":3, "Sunday":2} # number a people needed a to day work.

for day in Days[0:2]: # Monday and Tuesday only
    for employee in Employees:
        prob += pulp.lpSum(avail[employee, day, shift] for shift in      
Shift_pattern_1)==requests[employee][day]

for day in Days[2:3]: #wednesday
    for employee in Employees:
        prob += pulp.lpSum(avail[employee, day, shift] for shift in     
 Shift_pattern_Master)==requests[employee][day]

 ....more code to finish the week.........
```

When i complete the entire code from above, I get 35 constraints.

my attempt was to use if and else to shorten the code and i only get 30 constraints.  i know the problem is "if Week1[day]==2" because some constraints are missing.

1. i don't know where to put that if statement, or
2. is there a better way to be more pythonic?

   for day in Days:
       if Week1[day]==2:
           for employee in Employees:
               prob += pulp.lpSum(avail[employee, day, shift] for shift in
   Shift_pattern_1)==requests[employee][day]
       else:
           prob += pulp.lpSum(avail[employee, day, shift] for shift in Shift_pattern_Master)==requests[employee][day]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the unique day is Wednesday you want to do:

```
for day in Days: 
   if day=="Wednesday": 
      for employee in Employees: 
          prob += pulp.lpSum(avail[employee, day, shift] for shift in Shift_pattern_1)==requests[employee][day] 
   else:
      for employee in Employees: 
          prob += pulp.lpSum(avail[employee, day, shift] for shift in Shift_pattern_Master)==requests[employee][day]
```

however, I think you actually want the above condition so you just need to include the employees loop

```
for day in Days: 
   if Week1[day]==2: 
      for employee in Employees: 
          prob += pulp.lpSum(avail[employee, day, shift] for shift in Shift_pattern_1)==requests[employee][day] 
   else:
      for employee in Employees: 
          prob += pulp.lpSum(avail[employee, day, shift] for shift in Shift_pattern_Master)==requests[employee][day]
```

Comment: Hi Stuart,  thanks again.  it worked.  I have no clue i needed that.  these 2d nested dictionary is very complex for me. Now I can move on to the next part.